# Selectboxit Load Time

Tags: javascript, select

I am using the Selectboxit js plugin on select fields on my page. When the page loads there is a slight delay where the default select box shows before the selectboxit style is applied.

Is it possible to hide the default select box from showing until the selectboxit style is applied, and if so which class would need to be targeted in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide your selects in your CSS, the plugin will show the new ones automatically:

```
select{
    display: none;
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo